# Intuition for Coproduct of Grouplike vs Primitive elements in a Coalgebra?

Tags: hopf-algebras, coalgebras

I'm trying to understand Hopf Algebras as a physicist with a limited background in abstract algebra, and I might be in a little over my head.

In particular I'm trying to wrap my head around the fact that the coproduct in a group algebra $k[G]$ is given by

$$\Delta(g) = g \otimes g$$

But the coproduct in e.g. a tensor algebra $\otimes V$ is given by

$$\Delta(x) = x \boxtimes 1 + 1 \boxtimes x$$

My understanding is that in general elements of a coalgebra are either "grouplike" or "primitive" depending on whether they act like the first or second example. And I am (in theory) able to show that these two definitions are correct based on the axioms for the coproduct.

But I'm having trouble wrapping my head around conceptually why these things are defined like this. Why shouldn't the group coproduct be $e_g \otimes g + g \otimes e_g$? Or is that that *would* define a coalgebra, but the structure just isn't compatible with the group algebra such that you can construct a bialgebra / Hopf algebra with it?

Comment: This is a long story and you really need at least some background in abstract algebra to appreciate it. An easy comment is that the comultiplication in a Hopf algebra has to be multiplicative and you can check that $e \otimes g + g \otimes e$ is not. Similarly in the tensor algebra case the comultiplication has to be linear and you can check that, for example, $x \otimes x$ is not. Beyond that it's hard to say anything without a clearer sense of what you think comultiplications are for.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm trying to understand what comultiplications are for! That's why I'm trying to make sense of the constructions. It is a ... hard subject to penetrate.

Comment: Why do you say, though, that comultiplication has to be multiplicative in one case and linear in the other? Are these actually coproducts in two different categories? If so that would explain my confusion.

Comment: The comultiplication always has to be both. I'm just telling you how to see that in each of these cases the other choice of comultiplication doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you studying Hopf algebras? They have different applications and in those applications comultiplications are used somewhat differently. You mentioned physics - are you studying quantum groups?

Comment: Honestly I was just trying to understand the concepts because I keep coming across them in different settings. I'm interested in QFT so representation theory is relevant; quantum groups less-so (for now). Allegedly they're also used on Feynman diagrams. But more recently I heard about Hopf algebras in the context of machine learning and type theory. Mostly I just want my brain to stop turning off when I came across the words "antipode" or "Hopf convolution". So far no luck. I know what the things are but am having trouble making sense of it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't written with the precision or the comprehensiveness of a QY, but hopefully helps with intuition (which is my goal here). It is written from the perspective of quantum groups (and when I talk about Hopf algebras that are not quantum groups I am liable to stray in accuracy).

In quantum groups, a Hopf algebra $A$ can be thought of as an algebra of functions on an object that has a multiplication, identity, and an inverse map.

For example, let $G$ be a finite group, and $C(G)$ the algebra of complex-valued continuous functions (in the finite case all functions $G\to\mathbb{C}$ are continuous). The group $G$ has a multiplication $m:G\times G\to G$, $(g,h)\to g\cdot h$, an identity $e\in G$, and an inverse $g\mapsto g^{-1}$.

We want the comultiplication to be the transpose of the multiplication. That is:

$$\Delta(f)(g,h)=f(m(g,h))=f(g\cdot h)\qquad (g,h\in G,\,f\in C(G)).$$

This means that $f\mapsto \Delta f$ is going from a function on $G$ to a function on $G\times G$.

For multiplicative and linear:

> *For compact Hausdorff spaces $X$, $Y$, for every continuous function $\phi:Y\rightarrow X$, the map $\pi:C(X)\rightarrow C(Y)$:
> $$\pi(f)=f\circ \phi\qquad (f\in C(X)).$$*
> *is a unital $*$-homomorphism, in particular linear and multiplicative.*

So the transpose of the continuous $m:G\times G\to G$ is a $*$-homomorphism $C(G)\mapsto C(G\times G)$. Now we envoke the isomorphism:

$$C(G\times G)\cong C(G)\otimes C(G) \qquad(\text{ algebraic tensor product}).$$

This gives a map $\Delta:C(G)\to C(G)\otimes C(G)$.

Now that we have linearity we can consider $\Delta$ on the basis of delta functions, $\delta_g\in C(G)$. It shouldn't take you long to show that:

$$\Delta(\delta_g)=\sum_{t\in G}\delta_{gt^{-1}}\otimes \delta_t,$$

and e.g. coassociativity of $\Delta$ 'up' in $C(G)$ is inherited from associativity 'down' in $G$.

---

This is the one I don't know so much:

Consider the additive group $(\mathbb{C}^N,\cdot)$:
$$(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_N)\cdot (b_1,b_2,\dots,b_N)=(a_1+b_1,a_2+b_2,\dots,a_N+b_N)\qquad (a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{C}).$$
Consider the algebra $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C}^N)$ of polynomial functions $\mathbb{C}^N\to \mathbb{C}$. This is generated by the coordinate functions $x_i\in\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C}^N)$:

$$x_i(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_N)=a_i.$$

We want the comultiplication $\Delta$ to be the transpose of the multiplication $\cdot$ so that:

$$\Delta(x_i)(a,b)=x_i(a\cdot b)=a_i+b_i.$$

Being very fast and loose here (!!) we can see where the formula $\Delta(x_i)=x_i\otimes 1+1\otimes x_i$ comes from:

$$\Delta(x_i)(a\otimes b)=(x_i\otimes 1+1\otimes x_i)(a\otimes b)=x_i(a)\otimes 1(b)+1(a)\otimes x_i(b)\cong a_i+b_i.$$

---

With the group algebra... let's play a little fast and loose here and consider the group algebra $\mathbb{C}G$ as an algebra of functions on the algebra of functions $C(G)$. I guess that isn't so bad... but the multiplication we are transposing is not the multiplication in the group... but in the algebra of functions... and this is just the pointwise multiplication (this can make more sense because the pointwise multiplication is a multiplication $C(G)\otimes C(G)\to C(G)$).
$$m(u,v)(g)=u(g)\,v(g)\qquad (u,v\in C(G),\,g\in G).$$

We are viewing $\mathbb{C}G$ as functions on $C(G)$ by duality, by the evaluation:

$$g(f):=f(g)\qquad (f\in C(G),\,g\in \mathbb{C}G),$$

by seeing $g\in \mathbb{C}G$ also as an element of $G$.

So the comultliplication here should be:

$$\Delta(g)(u\otimes v)=g(m(u\otimes v))=g(uv) =uv(g)=u(g)v(g)\qquad (g\in \mathbb{C}G,\,u,v\in C(G)).$$
And we can check this against:

$$\Delta(g)(u\otimes v)=(g\otimes g)(u\otimes v)=(g(u)\otimes g(v))=u(g)\otimes v(g)\cong u(g)v(g).$$

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.